# General time reversible model of evolution and Felsenstein model

Tags: evolution, mathematical-models, book-recommendation, literature

I would like to get suggestions for the books related to **General time reversible model of evolution** and **Felsenstein model** etc. Specifically the mathematical treatment of these topics and concepts related to **general balance** and **detailed balance** etc. Can someone point out any books, links etc related to these.

Comment: I never heard of these terms. To satisfy my curiosity and assuming that you have some reference, can you please provide a link to the definitions of these things (or to the original articles)? `Time reversible model of evolution` kinda sound like `coalescent theory`. Are you sure those are not the same thing? There is a very good book by John Wakely called [Introduction to Coalescent Theory](http://www.amazon.ca/Coalescent-Theory-Introduction-John-Wakeley/dp/0974707759/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418802756&sr=8-1&keywords=coalescent+theory).

Comment: You can find some information, with references to the original papers, on this Wikpedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Models_of_DNA_evolution#GTR:_Generalised_time-reversible_.28Tavar.C3.A9_1986.29.5B9.5D (I won't try to offer a summary, because it's not by field.)

Answer (score 1):

The classic answer would be Joe Felsenstein's [Inferring Phylogenies](http://zmmu.msu.ru/files/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/felsenstein-2004_inferr_phylog.pdf). It has substantial technical discussion of GTR and Felsenstein models, among others.

However, it does not have any index entries for "general balance" or "detailed balance". I was not familiar with these terms, so I googled them and they do not appear to be common terms in the phylogenetics field.

These terms do pop up in the [MCMC literature](https://sites.engineering.ucsb.edu/%7Eshell/che210d/Monte_Carlo.pdf) a bit regarding transition probabilities, so it seems likely that it is somewhat related in terms of underlying math. However, I think that you are more likely to find phylogeneticists talking about "stationary" or "equilibrium" models rather than in terms of "balance". Possibly a difference in terminology between fields.

It might be helpful to know more about what you mean by these terms and why you are interested in them, in the form of links or otherwise.

Comment: I was curious to read about these when I was doing course work. Thanks for the response. Now I have moved into a different field. But I will go through it when I find free time.

Comment: Of course- I have started answering older unanswered questions because I think it's useful for future users at least. It is understandable you might have moved on, this is from 5 years ago after all!